# Why do methods in Swift can have arguments with no type?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

It's a very beginner question, but for I always wondered that for example in this method:

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`

Why do we have `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as an argument? I understand that `application` will be of type `UIApplication` and launchOptions will be of type `UIApplicationLaunchWithOptionsKey: any`, but why do we have just this 'stub' there called `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, if you know what I mean?

Also, what does the underscore mean before the first argument? I had to put that there many times so my functions would work.

Comment: That's the [argument label](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166)

Comment: Got you! Thanks for the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift, all parameters are named. However, sometimes this can become cumbersome or lead to weird parameter names inside of functions. For instance, if you have a function that looks like

```
func makeNewThing(fromDifferentThing: SomeThing)
```

it would feel weird to refer to the function's argument as `fromDifferentThing` inside the function.

To work around that, Swift lets you give the same function argument *two* names. One argument name will be used **outside** the function, and the other name will be used **inside** the function. The outer argument name is called the **argument label** and the inner name is usually just called the **parameter name**.

So in the case of my example, you could define your function as

```
func makeNewThing(fromDifferentThing thing: SomeThing)
```

and then refer to the argument as `thing` inside the function, but call the function as

```
makeNewThing(fromDifferentThing: thing)
```

The underscore is also related to this. Some functions don't really need to explain what their argument is, so Swift allows you to say the first argument of your function has *no argument label*. You would call such a function simply as:

```
function(argument1, label2: argument2, label3: argument3...)
```

and define it as:

```
func function(_ argument1: Type1, label2 argument2: Type2, /* ...and so on */)
```

Comment: Not all parameters are named – `func foo(_: String) {}` is useless, but legal.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that `application` will be of type `UIApplication` and `launchOptions` will be of type `[IApplicationLaunchWithOptionsKey: any]`
>
> what does the underscore mean before the first argument?

These two questions are related. The first of the two names is called *argument label*. If present, this is what you write in front of the colon when invoking the method. If absent, the parameter name becomes its label. If you don’t want an argument label for a parameter, write an underscore (`_`) instead.

Here is the summary of these three options:

- **Have an argument label and a name** - `func foo(bar baz:String)`, call `foo(bar:"Hello")`
- **Have only an argument name** - `func foo(baz:String)`, call `foo(baz:"Hello")`
- **Use underscore `_` for argument label** - `func(_ baz:String)`, call `foo("Hello")`

Comment: In this case, I would also add, that the argument labels are used for 'historical' reasons. As in Objective-C the function is called `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`. So when converting it to Swift, they used the argument labels for making it look similar to the Objective-C pendant.

Comment: So if you don't add an underscore, when you invoke the method you don't need to specify any string, just the value you want to pass in (similar to JavaScript)?

Comment: @konyv12 It's the other way around: if you add underscore, then you can pass parameters without a label. See the edit.

Comment: The standard 'foo' and 'bar' function names and parameters don't really show the benefit of how Swift does things.

Comment: @SteveIves That was my intention - I wanted to illustrate the syntactic differences in three short lines deprived of meaning. I am assuming that the benefits of argument labels are self-evident.